# Modify materialized view query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to modify Materialized view query . Is is possible to do the same without droping and recreating it.

Answer (score 28):

No, you cannot alter the query of a materialized view without dropping it.

The CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW syntax does not support that feature.

The ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW is used to modify an existing materialized view in one or more of the following ways:

- To change its storage characteristics
- To change its refresh method, mode, or time
- To alter its structure so that it is a different type of materialized view
- To enable or disable query rewrite

---

See Oracle 12c Release 1 Manual for:

- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW syntax:
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_6002.htm#i2145767
- ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW syntax:
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_2002.htm#SQLRF00808

Answer (score 8):

For conditions where you're not sure whether the MVIEW exists or not (which is what CREATE OR REPLACE is really good for), I use;

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW name_of_mview';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -12003 THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('MVIEW does not exist, which was somewhat expected');
            ELSE
                RAISE;
            END IF;
END;
/

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW name_of_mview ... AS SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can leave the mview in place.  If your concern is to minimize downtime while the new mview instantiates (because you didn't use a prebuilt table), you can do the following.

1. Create a new table called mview_1 on prebuilt table
2. Once it has been created you can drop the old one
3. create or replace view mview as select * from mview_1

Now, whenever you need to rebuild you will be able to do so with little to no downtime since you can simple point the view to the new table/mview going forward.

Comment: Downtime can be zero if you point your queries and code to a synonym (or standard view) and switch it from the wrong materialized view to the new one (and back when you have to modify it again). The creation of the materialized view can take all the time it needs, you just change the pointer when it's ready in a matter of milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a new feature in a later Oracle version, but I've found this works nicely:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mview PRESERVE TABLE;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mview
ON PREBUILT TABLE ...
```

Comment: Note the "PRESERVE TABLE" clause, which keeps your original table in place. Then you can define the new definition to the database, and the table doesn't get refreshed until you do it manually (for complex queries).

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to make a cascade drop view, it could be dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You *MIGHT* be able to make use of the existing MV as the source of a [prebuilt table for the new MV](http://hemantoracledba.blogspot.com/2009/03/materialized-view-on-prebuilt-table.html)

A lot depends on what you are doing to the query of course. If you are adding a column, for example, you'll need refresh everything to get its new value.

PS. The quick way of turning the existing MV into a table would be partition exchange but watch out for [gotchas](http://oracle-online-help.blogspot.com/2008/05/ora-14097-when-using-materialized-view.html). Then you manipulate the table to match the new result set and create the new MV based on the manipulated table.