# Oracle - materialized view - how to altering

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I need to change the structure of my materialized view in Oracle.
I am unable to drop this view and recreate it.
Is it possible to change the structure on the materialized view with: alter?

Thank's for any answer.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html) shows the alterations that are allowed. Your question doesn't explain what you are trying to change, so it isn't clear if what you want might fall under "alter its structure so that it is a different type of materialized view".

Comment: Could you please add more information and some code with example what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The answer to your queries with other possibilities you might be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274681/modify-materialized-view-query#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20cannot%20alter%20the,more%20of%20the%20following%20ways%3A&text=To%20enable%20or%20disable%20query%20rewrite